# Which function in Tensorflow is similar to expand_as in Pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to adapt some code from Pytorch to Tensorflow, though I'm not so familiar with the latter.

I use `expand_as` in my old code. Is there any similar function which can be used in Tensorflow?

Comment: You can probably use broadcasting. I don't think TF has a similar function.

Comment: Actually, I want to do concat in the next step. As I know, broadcast can only be used in add and multiply?Do you know how to utilize broadcacst for concat operation?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`tf.broadcast_to`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/broadcast_to) which has been introduced in TF 1.9 (initially under the name `tf.contrib.framework.broadcast_to`).